# JIRA, anyone non-authorized user can to see issues

Tags: jira

### 1. Summary

I can't make, that any non-authorized Internet user can to see issues of my projects.

---

### 2. Task

Many years I use GitLab/BitBucket/GitHub issues. All 3 web-services use permissions scheme:

- any Internet user may view issues without authorization;
- any free authorized user can create and comment issues.

I want to have similar behavior for JIRA.

---

### 3. Data

I have cloud JIRA Core + JIRA Software  [**license for non-commercial open source products**](https://www.atlassian.com/software/views/open-source-license-request).

- [**URL**](https://www.atlassian.com/software/views/open-source-license-request)
- [**Example issue link**](https://kristinita.atlassian.net/browse/GR-1)

At the time if non-JIRA user go to link, he will see an offer to login.

[image: Login offer]

---

### 4. Not helped

All actions no effect.

#### 4.1. Browse Projects anyone

I read this questions:

- [**Allowing anonymous access to your project**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/allowing-anonymous-access-to-your-project-938847186.html)
- [**How can I allow non-logged in users to view issues**](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-can-I-allow-non-logged-in-users-to-view-issues/qaq-p/364179)
- [**Is there a way to allow anonymous users to see Jira issues or Agile gadgets?**](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Is-there-a-way-to-allow-anonymous-users-to-see-Jira-issues-or/qaq-p/12391)

`JIRA settings` → `Issues` → `Permission schemes` → `Default permission scheme` → I change permissions to `anyone`:

[image: Anyone permission]

#### 4.2. Associate with a project

- [**How to associate a permission scheme with a project**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/configuring-project-permission-schemes-868982875.html)

[image: Associate a permission scheme with a project]

I can't do these actions.

`JIRA` → `Projects`:

**or**

`JIRA settings` → `Projects` → `Projects`

[image: JIRA Projects]

I select G-Rights (my test project name):

[image: G-Rights]

I don't find in any place `Permissions` and/or `Actions` items.

#### 4.3. Site access

`JIRA settings` → `User management` → `Site access` → I check `Anyone can join` → `Save changes`.

[image: Site access]

#### 4.4. Security levels

- [**Allow Public to View JIRA Issues**](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Allow-Public-to-View-JIRA-Issues/qaq-p/240009)
- [**How can I allow non-logged in users to view issues**](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Is-there-a-way-to-allow-anonymous-users-to-see-Jira-issues-or/qaq-p/12391#M5243)

`JIRA settings` → `Issues` → `Permission schemes` → I set `Set Issue Security` to `anyone`:

[image: Set issue security]

`JIRA settings` → `Issues` → `Issue security schemes` → I try both security levels: `None` and `Group (Anyone)`:

[image: Security levels]

Comment: Could you also share a screenshot from the project settings? Is the default permission scheme associated to your project? What are the global permissions from your cloud instance?